# I want to print list of element within a loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some List of web element and I want to print all the elements inside one loop.How can I do this?.I am not sure how to do..Below i put my code that is not work.. Any help will be appreciated

```
List<WebElement> Pid=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='optimizely-propertyid recommend-row-target']"));
List<WebElement> Ptitle=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-des listing-thumb-title property-wide-block-title']/a"));
List<WebElement> Pprice=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-price-image list-view']/a/span"));
List<WebElement> psleeps=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-price with-rating']/span/a"));
List<WebElement> Prating=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='rating-text']"));

for(WebElement e:Pid){

    System.out.println(e.getText());

    System.out.println(e.Ptitle.getText());
    System.out.println(Pprice.getText());


}
```

Comment: that is not work. What is the output/err msg you are getting?

Comment: its shows syntax error

Comment: what you mean by e.Ptitle.getText() & Pprice.getText() inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume all the list have same number of elements. Then you can print as given below.

```
List<WebElement> Pid=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='optimizely-propertyid recommend-row-target']"));
        List<WebElement> Ptitle=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-des listing-thumb-title property-wide-block-title']/a"));
        List<WebElement> Pprice=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-price-image list-view']/a/span"));
        List<WebElement> psleeps=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='see-the-world-price with-rating']/span/a"));
        List<WebElement> Prating=wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='rating-text']"));

        for(int i=0;i<Pid.size();i++){
            System.out.println(Pid.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Ptitle.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Pprice.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(psleeps.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(Prating.get(i).getText());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`e` is a `WebElement` from the `Pid` list. You can't use it to call another list. You also can't use `getText()` on a list.

You can't use one loop to print 5 different lists, however you can create a method that receives `List<WebElement>` as parameter and print it

```
public void printList(List<WebElement> list) {
    for(WebElement item : list) {
        System.out.println(item .getText());
    }
}
```

Uses:

```
printList(Pid);
printList(Ptitle);
//...
```

As a side note, variables should start with small letter `pid`, `ptitle` etc.